# Why PasswordBox is Sealed in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, passwords, sealed

A simple question, but google has no answer on that!
I'm hitting a wall today, because the [PasswordBox in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is Sealed. I have no idea why they do that. Is somebody have an idea on that?

Comment: What would you need to subclass it for?

Comment: Rather than worry about why PasswordBox is sealed, can you explain what you are actually trying to accomplish as that is the real problem you need to solve? :)

Comment: I succeed by using composition instead of inheritance, but I think this is still a valid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PasswordBox isn't just sealed in Silverlight, but also WPF. According to the Silverlight team it is sealed because of [security concerns](http://forums.silverlight.net/post/106410.aspx), but they don't mention what those concerns are.

I don't see how any of the vulnerabilities [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471266/why-passwordbox-is-sealed-in-silverlight/7471292#7471292) are valid since as a developer you have full access to the typed in Password which you can do whatever you want with.

Answer (score 8):

Because if you can subclass it, you can introduce vulnerabilities into it.

Some vulnerabilities that might be introduced:

1. Accessing `protected` members.
2. Creating special accessors to `protected` members.
3. 3rd Party Injection - someone else subclasses your class to get at the password.

Comment: Can you explain *how* subclassing could introduce vulnerabilities?

Comment: I don't understand. The only protected members are the ones invoked before events like `OnMouseMove`. There's certainly no harm in accessing or exposing those. Since `Password` is already public, how is there harm in allowing subclasses?

Comment: Like the others, I don't fully understand the arguments. Can you provide an example?